# Как работает данный полифилл?

Tags: javascript, html

Может конечно стоит пойти поспать,но пояснение  хотя бы по методу sourceIndex мне не помешает.

```js
(function() {
  var el = document.documentElement;
  if (!el.compareDocumentPosition && el.sourceIndex !== undefined) {

    Element.prototype.compareDocumentPosition = function(other) {
      return (this != other && this.contains(other) && 16) +
        (this != other && other.contains(this) && 8) +
        (this.sourceIndex >= 0 && other.sourceIndex >= 0 ?
          (this.sourceIndex < other.sourceIndex && 4) +
          (this.sourceIndex > other.sourceIndex && 2) : 1
        ) + 0;
    }
  }
}());
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/compare-document-position#podderzhka-v-ie8

Comment: Оттуда он и был взят,ну да ладно

Comment: Ну вроде там есть пояснение про sourceIndex, не?